# XCode 4 - Array Of Buttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm trying to learn the Mac OS and iOs developing with XCode 4. My first application is a game for mac: **Reversi** (Othello).
I built my interface with a **8x8 grid of green buttons** but now i don't understand how to link them in my AppDelegate class. How should i define an array of IBOutlet? I can't create 64 different attributes :D
I read that iPhone developers can use `IBOutletCollection` but i can't find a way to use it in my mac application...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Mac, you can simply use one `NSMatrix` outlet. Create a single button in Interface Builder, then select "Embed in > Matrix" from the "Editor" menu. When you resize the matrix while holding the option (alt) key, it will create a grid of multiple buttons instead of resizing the button itself.